# Integrating material UI example with next.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am trying to quickly create a dashboard with next.js and react.js as a front end using tempaltes from material-ui.

Using next-create-app and find it easy enough to get something up and running but I just can't seem to integrate this dashboard. 
https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react

I realise that material UI has a github link for next.js here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs but for some reason I can't install it either...

when using the curl function i get locked out for some reason. I can use git functions fine though - maybe that would solve the issue? I don't think there's a way to get that specific branch though.

Appreciate any help - I realise it's a simple question yet I've had some difficulty with it so would love some help.

Comment: Hi what do you mean by "I can't seem to integrate this dashboard" ? Are you getting errors ?  as for the CURL function being locked out, what error message are you getting ?

Comment: Hi Michael, what about `git clone` the whole repository and extract the example template you wannt use?